# Regular expression in Groovy not returning expected results

Tags: regex, groovy

I've been working on a regular expression with the following requirements.

```
    // Must be exactly 17 characters
    // Must only contain letters and numbers
    // Cannot contain the letters ‘I’, ‘O’ or ‘Q’
    // Must contain at least 1 alpha and 1 numeric character.
```

Thanks to some help on in another topic I managed to get a regular expression of

`/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-hj-npr-z0-9]{17})$/`

I was able to validate this as per https://regex101.com/r/cVz4b9/4/.

For some reason when I try this in Groovy though I don't get the same results.

```
def regex = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-hj-npr-z0-9]{17})$/
println​ ('B1cCdDeEfFgGhHwww' ==~ regex)​​​
```

For example the below Groovy script prints false when I'm expecting true. Perhaps I'm not escaping something I should be? I am using the slashy string so I'm not sure why this would not work?

If anyone can pick out what's wrong that would help me a lot.

thanks

Comment: I guess you forgot to mention case sensitivity there. Otherwise use `[a-hA-Hj-nJ-NpPr-zR-Z0-9]`.

Comment: Why not do it as 4 separate steps, rather than one horrible one, which you will hate yourself for when you come back to update it when someone has another crazy rule to add

Comment: Yes. I'm starting to think that myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that case doesn't matter by your example so you could just add the case insensitivity flag (?i)

```
def regex = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])((?i)[a-hj-npr-z0-9]{17})$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, you can take the following ordered (and concise) approach:

- Start with case insensitivity flag: `(?i)` . Since not revoked,
  it "works" till the end of the regex.
- Put both positive lookaheads concerning a single digit and letter
  placed anywhere: `(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])`.
- Put negative lookahead concerning 3 "forbidden" chars, but you must
  forbid also "_", matched by `\w` (see below): `(?!.*[ioq_])`.
- Put the main clause concerning 17 word chars: `[\w]{17}` (instead of
  mentioning letters and digits separately, remember that "_" was
  forbidden earlier).

`^` and `$` are not needed, since `==~` checks whether **the entire** text
    is matched by the regex.

To sum up the regex can be: `(?i)(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*[ioq_])[\w]{17}`.

Comment: thanks. This was an awesome answer. I marked the other one as accepted because it was very close to what I already had. But this answer gives me a lot of learnings.